# Is the inverse of a matrix orthogonal to the original matrix?

Tags: matrices

Can someone please tell me if the inverse of a symmetric matrix is orthogonal to the original matrix?

i.e. If M, the original matrix = PDP^-1 then is P^-1 orthogonal to P?

Comment: Is the inverse of identity orthogonal to identity?

Comment: Wait, what does it mean for a matrix to be orthogonal to another one? I haven't heard this terminology before.

Comment: When we say a (real) matrix *is* orthogonal, we mean that its inverse is equal to its transpose.  AFAIK if you want to talk about one matrix being "orthogonal" to another matrix (a relation between matrices), this requires a definition.

Comment: So this question is related to one of my homework problems where it says do an orthogonal similarity transformation of a 3x3 matrix. I couldn't find anything on orthogonal similarity transformations so I just found P and D that fulfills that equation I mentioned in the problem statement. I am not sure my answer is correct though, because when I inverse P it is not equal to the transpose of P...

Comment: An orthogonal similarity transformation $P^{-1} M P$ is a similarity transformation where $P$ is orthogonal.  Apparently you found a similarity transformation, but not an orthogonal one.

Comment: Could you point me in the direction of an example? I'm not sure how to find an orthogonal similarity transformation. So for D we find the eigenvalues. For P do we just replace P-1 with transpose of P and solve a system of equations to find the matrix P? In other words, we don't have to solve for the eigenvectors?

Comment: One example of an orthogonal similarity transformation is a rotation.